# Rewrite php page with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, ftp, url-rewriting

I am creating a form at poll.php?code=STRINGHERE

I want to rewrite it with .htaccess to do WEBSITE.com/STRINGHERE
I have done it before but don't remember what I need to do in the .htaccess its something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewiteRule ^(\w.+)$ ./poll.php?code=$1
```

Although I might be wrong. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewiteRule ^([^/]+)$ ./poll.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And if you need to redirect the browser when requests are made directly to poll.php:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+poll\.php\?code=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: Hey Jon, so I am not going to lie I had forgot I asked this question but your answer was spot on. Thanks!